# Get the product info/images from another site using SKU

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have setup a **woocommerce** site and which has over 500 products with their SKUs.
I need to get the description and images for those products from the old site which is a non-wordpress site.
There are over 500 products so can't do it manually for each product

The common factor here is Product SKU which is a part of URL on the old site on product single page.

The method I have in mind is to write a script which will:

1. get all the SKU from the wordpress site(which is easy)
2. in some way using the old site URL it will check each product against those SKU ( as the SKU is part of the URL on old site )
3. For the matching SKU get the product description and images
4. Add that description and image to the respective product on the new site.

Will really appreciate if someone can guide me on the right path as how to achieve this or suggest any better method to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has a solid [REST API](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/), using this you can query your products for any information you need.

There's even a useful [WooCommerce API wrapper/library](http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2014/02/10/woocommerce-rest-api-client-library/) available.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But how do I access the product data from the old site? As it is not built with woocommerce system.